# AXIS2: JNDI lookup of name ConnectionFactory returned a org.jboss.mq.SpyConnectionFactory while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected

Tags: wso2, jbossmq, wso2-esb

I installed a fresh WSO2 ESB version 4.2.3 (last stable up to now) and I configured the JMS transport in the `axis2.xml` file as following:

```
<!-- Configuration for JBoss 4.2.2 GA MQ -->
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
    <parameter name="SMSOUTQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs" locked="false">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">jnp://192.168.10.125:1100</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">ConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination" locked="true">queue/SMSOUTQueue</parameter>
    </parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

Immediately after, during the startup an error has been found:

```
15:09:16,585 INFO  [STDOUT] 15:09:16,585 ERROR [BaseUtils] JNDI lookup of name ConnectionFactory returned a org.jboss.mq.SpyConnectionFactory while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected
15:09:16,587 INFO  [STDOUT] 15:09:16,585 ERROR [ListenerManager] Couldn't initialize the jmstransport listener
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseTransportException: JNDI lookup of name ConnectionFactory returned a org.jboss.mq.SpyConnectionFactory while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseUtils.handleException(BaseUtils.java:167)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:522)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(JMSConnectionFactory.java:92)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.loadConnectionFactoryDefinitions(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:58)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.<init>(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener.doInit(JMSListener.java:58)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListenerEx.init(AbstractTransportListenerEx.java:62)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager.init(ListenerManager.java:84)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:386)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:916)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:330)
```

I found a lot of posts where people say to remove the `...WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar`, because otherwise synapse doesn't work with any external JMS broker (I found same answer also for Mule ESB), but for me this solution doesn't work.

The problem is very similar [to this link](http://rajikak.blogspot.it/2011/04/jms-error-jndi-lookup-of-name.html).

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late reply. But I also encountered same error and able to fix.When trying to connect to a JMS queue deployed in a JBoss Server from WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 and even with removing the jar geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar,your mentioned issue was not fixed.

The reason for that is,in your added jboss related jars to ESB/repository/components/lib,there are some other jars,exposing the implementation for javax.jms.*. For example in my case there were two additional jars called jboss-j2ee.jar and jbossall-client.jar exposing  javax.jms.*. What I did was I opened the two jars and removed the exposing package part of javax.jms.* from both.Then the issue was fixed.

Thanks;